# How do you enable HTTP GET for submitJob for a GPService?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, geoprocessing, arcgis-rest-api, configuration

I published a GPService to ArcGIS Server 10.2--the service is a copy of an existing service with a different name. I receive no errors during publishing, however I get 404 errors when attempting to submit a job via HTTP GET.  HTTP Post works fine--job is successfully submitted and it completes successfully.

I did not set up the original service, so I'm thinking I missed a checkbox or some configuration during the publishing process.  Is there a way to enable HTTP GET for a GPService after it has been published?  If not, how do you enable during publishing?

Comment: You say "submit a job", so the task is ASYNC? Theres no check box to enable GET | POST. Both are viable options.404 is not found, I dont know why you'd get that when GETing vs POSTing. Maybe your input parameters are extremely long and you need to be POSTing?

Comment: Correct, Async and I'm testing from the HTML submitJob page, which has a GET and POST buttons.

Comment: Wow. Need more coffee. I was sure the HTTP GET was working with the original service but it wasn't. AND the calling application was POSTing, so that's a relief!